# Returning continuations from call/cc

Tags: scheme, continuations

Matt Might, in his posting on [continuations by example](http://matt.might.net/articles/programming-with-continuations--exceptions-backtracking-search-threads-generators-coroutines/), defines the helper function

```lisp
(define (current-continuation)
  (call/cc (lambda (cc) (cc cc))))
```

to grab and return the current continuation.  Why use `(cc cc)` to return the continuation?  Why not use `cc`:

```lisp
(define (current-continuation)
  (call/cc (lambda (cc) cc)))
```

Might's examples work identically with either version of `current-continuation`.  Is this just a matter of style, or is there a deeper issue at work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, just to remember `call/cc` in CPS is this:

```
(define (call/cc& f k)
  (f (lambda (v ignored-cont) (k v)) k))
```

So the first one does this:

```
(define (current-continuation k1)
  (call/cc& (lambda (cc k2) (cc cc k2)) k1))
```

The second one does this:

```
(define (current-continuation k1)
  (call/cc& (lambda (cc k2) (k2 cc)) k1))
```

Since `call/cc` will pass `k1` as `k2` and `cc` will use `k1` both will end up doing `(k1 cc)`. Thus there is no difference between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, ok.  If you'll forgive me the need to count on my fingers for this,  the definitions

```lisp
(define (current-continuation k1)
  (call/cc& (lambda (cc k2) (k2 cc)) k1))

(define (call/cc& f k)
  (f (lambda (v ignored-cont) (k v)) k))
```

turn the call

```lisp
(current-continuation after-cc-k)
```

into

```lisp
(call/cc& (lambda (cc k2) (k2 cc)) k1)
```

under the formal parameter bindings

```lisp
k1 = after-cc-k
```

which rewrites to

```lisp
(call/cc& (lambda (cc k2) (k2 cc)) after-cc-k)
```

which is defined as

```lisp
(f (lambda (v ignored-cont) (k v)) k)
```

under the formal parameter bindings

```lisp
f = (lambda (cc k2) (k2 cc))
k = after-cc-k
```

which rewrites to

```lisp
((lambda (cc k2) (k2 cc)) (lambda (v ignored-cont) (after-cc-k v)) after-cc-k)
```

which evaluates to

```lisp
(k2 cc)
```

under the formal parameter bindings

```lisp
cc = (lambda (v ignored-cont) (k1 v))
k2 = after-cc-k
```

which rewrites to

```lisp
(after-cc-k (lambda (v ignored-cont) (after-cc-k v)))
```

that is, return to the rest of the computation after the call to `current-continuation` the continuation for the rest of the computation after the call to `current-continuation`.

Now define

```lisp
(define (current-continuation k1)
  (call/cc& (lambda (cc k2) (cc cc k2)) k1))
```

which causes the call

```lisp
(current-continuation after-cc-k)
```

to be defined as

```lisp
(call/cc& (lambda (cc k2) (cc cc k2)) k1)
```

under the formal parameter binding

```lisp
k1 = after-cc-k
```

which rewrites to

```lisp
(call/cc& (lambda (cc k2) (cc cc k2)) after-cc-k)
```

which is defined as

```lisp
(f (lambda (v ignored-cont) (k v)) k)
```

under the formal parameter bindings

```lisp
f = (lambda (cc k2) (cc cc k2))
k = after-cc-k
```

which rewrites to

```lisp
((lambda (cc k2) (cc cc k2)) (lambda (v ignored-cont) (after-cc-k v)) after-cc-k)
```

which evaluates to

```lisp
(cc cc k2)
```

under the formal parameter bindings

```lisp
cc = (lambda (v ignored-cont) (after-cc-k v))
k2 = after-cc-k
```

which rewrites to

```lisp
((lambda (v ignored-cont) (after-cc-k v))
  (lambda (v ignored-cont) (after-cc-k v)) after-cc-k)
```

which evaluates to

```lisp
(after-cc-k v)
```

under the formal parameter bindings

```lisp
v = (lambda (v ignored-cont) (after-cc-k v))
ignored-cont = ...
```

which rewrites to

```lisp
(after-cc-k (lambda (v ignored-cont) (after-cc-k v)))
```

i.e., the same thing the other definition of `current-continuation` produced.  Whew.

Comment: Voted up for the nifty details 

Answer (score 1):

In the example exactly as written, there's no difference. However, the one that Might provides is more robust in the sense that the escape with the continuation can be more deeply nested, if desired. That is, you could write something like

```lisp
(define (current-continuation)
  (call/cc (lambda (cc) (+ 1234 (cc cc))))
```

```lisp
(define (current-continuation)
  (call/cc (lambda (cc) (printf "~v" (cc cc)))))
```

... or something similar, and you'd still get the same result. Basically, I think it's plausible to think, as an experienced continuations programmer, "yes, I want to escape with the continuation value". You're right, though, I believe the two definitions you provide are equivalent in all contexts. Proving it would take some thought, though.